# CMake set custom configuration name for target

Tags: c++, cmake

I have project called test_containers. It contains only cpp files with tests and CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)
project(test_containers)

set(source_files
    test_array.cpp
    test_linear_hash_table.cpp
    test_list.cpp
    test_set.cpp
    test_span.cpp
    test_stack.cpp
    test_string.cpp
    test_vector.cpp
)

foreach(source IN LISTS source_files)
    get_filename_component(name ${source} NAME_WE)
    add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}.${source})
    set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME}.${source} PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME ${name})
    target_sources(${PROJECT_NAME}.${source} PRIVATE ${source})
    target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}.${source} PRIVATE gtest_main wise_engine_cert)
    add_test(
        NAME ${name}
        COMMAND ${PROJECT_NAME}.${source}
    )
endforeach()
```

CMake generates bin files called test_array, test_linear_hash_table and etc. In CTest I see that all tests are called the same test_array, test_linear_hash_table and etc.

The problem is I don't know how to change configurations name. In CLion list of configurations I see something like - "test_containers.test_array.cpp". How to make custom configuration name like just simply "test_array"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this float your boat?

```
foreach(source IN LISTS source_files)
    get_filename_component(name ${source} NAME_WE)
    add_executable(${name})
    target_sources(${name} PRIVATE ${source})
    target_link_libraries(${name} PRIVATE gtest_main wise_engine_cert)
    add_test( NAME ${name} COMMAND ${name}
    )
endforeach()
```

Comment: @a.wise I was a bit confused at first because you called it a "configuration name". It's simply the **target**, i.e. what you specify in `add_executable()`. It's also what you use to specify... well, the *target*... of `target_sources()` and `target_link_libraries()`. I don't know which tutorial you copied your CMakeLists.txt from, but it overcomplicates things there a bit. Glad I could help.